# ajax control toolkit calendar startdate=datetime.now FromDate To Date Validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

how to validate FromDate and ToDat?
i'm using two textbox id-'FromDate', 'ToDate'

here is the client side code

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="FromDate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="FromDate" runat="server" width="158px"></asp:Textbox>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="FromDate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="ToDate" runat="server" width="158px"></asp:Textbox>
```

here is the backend code

```
CalendarExtender1.startdate=datetime.now
CalendarExtender2.startdate=datetime.now
```

i'd lik to know, if i select fromdate(5/1/2012), the selection for 'Todate' should be equal or greater then fromdate,,,
it shouldn't lesserthen 'fromdate' lesserdays should be disable

Answer (score 1):

you can work with a combination of the client and server side validation.

below alidation will work at client side to get a valid date from user.

```
<ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator3" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender3" ControlToValidate="FromDate" EmptyValueMessage="Prosim vpišite Datum začetka."  InvalidValueMessage="Please enter valid date." Display="None" TooltipMessage="Prosim vpišite Datum začetka."  EmptyValueBlurredText="Empty" ValidationGroup="Offers" />
```

And then you can have a date validation method at server side to comapare from and to date. as below

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Text));
                if (result < 0 || result == 0)
                {
                    // user input passed
                }
                else
                {
                    // error msg: "'To date' should be greater then 'From date'";
                }
```